# Aggregate Nested Pgsql query

Tags: postgresql, nested

I'm trying to query a table to get me some results, but the way I'm doing it gives me the error: ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested.

The table looks like this:

ID | canal_c1 | tarifacao | date | ativo_id

The query I'm trying is this:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(case when tarifacao = 'ForaPonta' then canal_c1 else 0 end) as ConsForaPonta,
  MAX(case when tarifacao = 'ForaPonta' then canal_c1 else 0 end) as DemForaPonta,
  ativo_id as ativo_id,
  data_leitura_inicio::date as date
FROM
  medicao
WHERE
  medicao.ativo_id in (45) AND 
  medicao.tipo_leitura = 'Consumo' AND 
  medicao.data_leitura_inicio >= '2017-01-01' AND 
  medicao.data_leitura_inicio < '2017-01-10'
GROUP BY
  medicao.ativo_id,
  medicao.data_leitura_inicio::date
```

That gives me result like these:
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwpMY.png)
And that's fine what I need now is the datetime from the DemForaPonta field, in order to do that I trying this, but got that error.

```
 MAX(case when tarifacao = 'ForaPonta' and 
 canal_c1 = MAX(case when tarifacao = 'ForaPonta' then canal_c1 else 0 end)
 then data_leitura_inicio end) as DateDemForaPonta
```

Do you know how I could achieve this?
Thanks.

Edit:
Here's an example, the query result is the intended result.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AH5B.png)

Comment: Please, can you put the data in a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or in text? its hard to get data from an image. I will try to take a look at the data latter.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to have an example with real data. But anyway, you can do what you need with nested selects, among other options.

**Nested SELECTs**

```
SELECT *,
  MAX(case when tarifacao = 'ForaPonta' and canal_c1 = DemForaPonta then data_leitura_inicio END)
  AS DateDemForaPonta
FROM(
    SELECT
      SUM(case when tarifacao = 'ForaPonta' then canal_c1 else 0 end) as ConsForaPonta,
      MAX(case when tarifacao = 'ForaPonta' then canal_c1 else 0 end) as DemForaPonta,
      ativo_id as ativo_id,
      data_leitura_inicio::date as date
    FROM
      medicao
    WHERE
      medicao.ativo_id in (45) AND 
      medicao.tipo_leitura = 'Consumo' AND 
      medicao.data_leitura_inicio >= '2017-01-01' AND 
      medicao.data_leitura_inicio < '2017-01-10'
    GROUP BY
      medicao.ativo_id,
      medicao.data_leitura_inicio::date
)data
```

Since I don't have data to test it, don't really know if it does the trick, but it should.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it did not work.
I attached a table and a query result example, appreciate if you take a look.